# Listview containing items with foreign key

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms.listview

I am building an application using Firebase and Xamarin.Forms, I have a `Listview` that shows requests. The thing is that one of the fields of the `Request` class contains an `Id` for an object of a second class.

What I want to do is to get the name of that item from the second class using the `Id` field that is located in `Requests` class. Can I do that with data binding? If I follow the normal flow it will show the `Id`.

Comment: you either need a read-only property on your class that will display the value of the FK, or use a ValueConverter to do it

Comment: I checked these solutions, they don't do what I need

Comment: of course they do - I'll expand in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your model has a `FK` property like this

```
public int FK { get; set; }
```

and FK points to a `Widget` object in `List<Widget>`, you could add a read-only property to your model like this

```
public string WidgetName 
{
    get {
      return Widgets.FirstOrDefault(w => w.ID == FK).Name;
    }
}
```

then you can just use `WidgetName` in your binding

if you don't want to modify your model, you could use the same approach in a `ValueConverter` that would convert `FK` into a `Name`, and use the converter in your binding

Comment: Amazing! Simple and easy! Thank you.

Comment: Just a question, I'm trying this out but Widgets is supposed to be a List, how can I pass this list to my model class?

Comment: However you like.  Widgets could be a static variable, or an object you pass via the constructor, or a dozen other approaches.